# Python 3.6 Проблема с конкатенацией строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Здравствуйте,

решаю задачку по преобразованию строк из двух текстовых файлов в нужный вид, в данный момент при попытке добавить в конец преобразованной строки фиксированный текст он съезжает на следующую строку

```
filename2 = r'C:\file2.txt'
filename4 = r'C:\file4.txt'
f2 = open(filename2)
lines2 = f2.readlines()
f2.close()
for lines in lines2:
    c = lines[:4] + lines[4:].replace(':', ';') + "test"
    f4.write(c)
```

Получаю такой результат:

```
bla:bla;bla
testbla:bla;bla
test
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы текст построчно добавлялся начиная с первой строки?

Comment: Подозреваю, из файла читается строка вместе с CRLF...

Comment: В считанных строках в конце присутствует перенос строки. Чтобы его убрать, можно делать `line = line.rstrip('\r\n')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного подхимичил и получилось это:

```
filename2 = r'C:\file2.txt'
filename4 = r'C:\file4.txt'

with open(filename2) as f2, open(filename4, mode='w') as f4:
    for line in f2:
        line = line.rstrip()
        new_line = line[:4] + line[4:].replace(':', ';') + "test\n"
        
        f4.write(new_line)
```

Comment: ничего, бывает)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, insolor, теперь всё работает как надо.

```
for lines in lines2:
    lines = lines.rstrip('\r\n')
    c = lines[:15] + lines[15:].replace(':', ';') + ";1;imap.mail.ru:993;" + '\n'
```